# Logback giving error Cannot cast object '3 gb' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize'

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, logback, logback-groovy

I have a springboot application and while trying to log using logback with groovy config I am getting following error:

```
    Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '3 gb' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
```

My groovy config file:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO

scan("60 seconds")
def LOG_PATH = "logs"
def LOG_ARCHIVE = "${LOG_PATH}/archive"



appender("RollingFile-Appender", RollingFileAppender) {
    file = "${LOG_PATH}/rollingfile.log"
    rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
        fileNamePattern = "${LOG_ARCHIVE}/Rainbow_Notifications.log%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        maxHistory = 30
        totalSizeCap = "3 gb"
    }
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%msg%n"
    }
}


logger("com.something", INFO, ["RollingFile-Appender"])
```

**Note:** I have tried even these strings:as file size: `3gb`, `3 gb`, `3GB`,`3096mb`,`3096 mb`,`3096 MB`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the line

```
    totalSizeCap = "3 gb"
```

with

```
    totalSizeCap = FileSize.valueOf("3 gb")
```

You'll need to add the line `import ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize;` as well.

The [`setTotalSizeCap` method of the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` class](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html#setTotalSizeCap(ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize))  takes a [`FileSize`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/util/FileSize.html) object, not a string.  The static `valueOf` method in `FileSize` should do the necessary conversion from string to `FileSize`.

Comment: It works for me too, thanx. But why in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/logback-configuration-using-groovy) author uses string literal?

Comment: @SergeyLinnik: I don't know.  I'll ask.